# search or filtering functionality in spring mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I have successfully set up all my pages and rendered my html using jpa. How would I go about making use of search box to filter items displayed on my page? I  will be making a query to the database and looking for results of a certain string, which I know how to do. I am confused with the part of the the search filtering after setting up a controller.

```
@Controller
public class SearchController {
    private GetAllBooks getAllBooksService;

    @Autowired
    public SearchController(GetAllComics service) {
        this.getAllBooksService= service;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="search", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public String show(@RequestParam("criteria") String criteria, Model model) {
        List<Issue> issues = getAllBooksService.getIssueRepository().getIssueBySearch(criteria);
        model.addAttribute("books",books);
        return "search";
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you want to do filtering work (client or api/server)?

Comment: What seems to be problem with your `#getIssueBySearch` method?  You're passing a string value which you want to use to filter your `Book` entities.  What's the confusion exactly?